# two lines in one telerik chart (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a class like this:

```
public class RadChartRow
{
public virtual string X { get; set; }
public virtual int Y { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I do this:

```
IList<RadChartRow>[] array = new IList<RadChartRow>[2];

array[0] = BlaRepository.GetBla1(Id1);
array[1] = BlaRepository.GetBla2(Id1,Id2);

ViewData["TimeSeries"] = array;
```

I cannot use the data in a strongly typed view so I have to use ViewData (could use a bag too though)

Anyway this is some view code:

```
<%= (Html.Telerik().Chart((IList<RadChartRow>[])ViewData["TimeSeries"])
        .Name("chart")
        .Theme("Web20")
        .Title(title => title
            .Text("Bla")
            .Visible(false)
        )
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Line(s => s[0].Y).Name("Bla").Color("gray").Markers(markers => markers.Type(ChartMarkerShape.Circle)).Labels(l => l.Position(ChartLineLabelsPosition.Above).Font("12px Arial, sans-serif").Visible(true));
            series.Line(s => s[1].Y).Name("Bla").Color("red").Markers(markers => markers.Type(ChartMarkerShape.Circle)).Labels(l => l.Position(ChartLineLabelsPosition.Above).Font("12px Arial, sans-serif").Visible(true));
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories(s => s[0].X).Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
        )      
    )
    %>
```

Unfortunatley this does not work. Is there a simple solution to depict the two sets of data in one chart?

Please note that the X values for both series are the same. Only the Y vaules differ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class needs a second Y property so that you can have 2 series.

```
public class RadChartRow
{
  public virtual string X { get; set; }
  public virtual int Y1 { get; set; }
  public virtual int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

The controller can return the list to the view instead of using ViewData.

```
    IList<RadChartRow> list = new List<RadChartRow>();

    RadChartRow rcr = new RadChartRow();
    rcr.X = "One";
    rcr.Y1 = 15;
    rcr.Y2 = 23;
    list.Add(rcr);
    rcr = new RadChartRow();
    rcr.X = "Two";
    rcr.Y1 = 8;
    rcr.Y2 = 3;
    list.Add(rcr);
    rcr = new RadChartRow();
    rcr.X = "Three";
    rcr.Y1 = 13;
    rcr.Y2 = 25;
    list.Add(rcr);
    rcr = new RadChartRow();
    rcr.X = "Four";
    rcr.Y1 = 25;
    rcr.Y2 = 32;
    list.Add(rcr);

    return View(list);
```

The only change to the view is to use the model that is passed to the view.

```
@model IList<RadChartRow>

(Html.Telerik().Chart(Model)
    .Name("chart")
    .Theme("Web20")
    .Title(title => title
        .Text("Bla")
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
      series.Line(s => s.Y1).Name("Bla1")
        .Color("gray")
        .Markers(markers => markers.Type(ChartMarkerShape.Circle))
        .Labels(l => l.Position(ChartLineLabelsPosition.Above).Font("12px Arial, sans-serif").Visible(true));
      series.Line(s => s.Y2).Name("Bla2")
        .Color("red")
        .Markers(markers => markers.Type(ChartMarkerShape.Circle))
        .Labels(l => l.Position(ChartLineLabelsPosition.Above).Font("12px Arial, sans-serif").Visible(true));
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
            .Categories(s => s.X)
            .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
    )
)
```

The chart should look like the one below.

[image: Chart]

**Update:**

If you do not want to use model binding, you can use ajax binding. In the view, set the databinding.

```
Html.Telerik().Chart<RadChartRow>()
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Chart2Ajax", "Chart"))
    .Name("chart")
```

In the controller, return an empty view for the view.

```
return View();
```

Then have a separate method for the ajax data binding.

```
  public ActionResult _Chart2Ajax()
  {
    IList<RadChartRow> list = new List<RadChartRow>();

    RadChartRow rcr = new RadChartRow();
    rcr.X = "One";
    rcr.Y1 = 15;
    rcr.Y2 = 23;
    list.Add(rcr);
    //.... code left out to save space

    return Json(list);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. Would like to keep my RadChartRow 2 dimensional though. Will accept anyway.